# MySQL join 3 calculation results

Tags: mysql, join

I have 3 different MySQL calculations, which I'd like to join. I need to be able to show lines where a sum may not exist for some column, or some invoice might not have a corporation ID.

I'm trying to get something like:

```
passport_amount | invoice_amount | balance_amount | corporation_id
------------------------------------------------------------------
           345  |       2345     |          56    |         56
```

So that I can work on these values in my application code by iterating the list once and not fetching data from the database three times, and then iterating three times to combine the values.

```
SELECT 
  sum(passports.amount) AS passports_amount, 
  companies.corporation_id 
FROM 
  passports
INNER JOIN 
  employees ON ( passports.employee_id = employees.id ) 
INNER JOIN 
  companies ON ( employees.company_id = companies.id ) 
WHERE 
  ((((passports.pass_type IN ('sport','culture','both')) 
    AND 
      (MONTH(passports.valid_from) >= 1 
      AND MONTH(passports.valid_from) <= 9 
      AND YEAR(passports.valid_from) = year(now()))) 
    AND (passports.removed = 0 
      AND passports.valid_from <= date('2014-09-29 11:55:26'))) 
  AND (companies.removed = 0) 
  AND companies.corporation_id IS NOT NULL) 
GROUP BY 
  companies.corporation_id;


SELECT 
  sum(invoices.amount) AS invoices_amount, 
  invoices.corporation_id 
FROM 
  invoices 
WHERE 
  ((((YEAR(sent_at) = 2014) 
    AND (invoices.product_type_id IN (2,3,4))) 
  AND 
    (invoices.removed = 0 
    AND invoices.activated = 1)) 
  AND invoices.corporation_id IS NOT NULL) 
GROUP BY 
  invoices.corporation_id;



SELECT 
  amount AS balance_amount, 
  business_id AS corporation_id 
FROM 
  invoice_balances 
WHERE 
  business_type = 'Corporation';
```

Comment: And from where `balance_amount` comes ?

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid From the third query, updated the field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine queries for balance and invoice amount using sub select in left join but this will look odd and can be expensive in terms of performance

```
SELECT 
  SUM(p.amount) AS passports_amount, 
  ii.invoices_amount,
  b.balance_amount,
  c.corporation_id 
FROM 
  passports p
INNER JOIN employees e ON ( p.e = e.id ) 
INNER JOIN companies c ON ( e.company_id = c.id ) 
/* Added left join for balance using subselect*/
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT amount AS balance_amount,   business_id AS corporation_id 
FROM   invoice_balances 
WHERE   business_type = 'Corporation'
) b ON (c.corporation_id  = b.corporation_id)
/* Added left join for invoices_amount using subselect*/
LEFT JOIN(
SELECT SUM(i.amount) AS invoices_amount, 
  i.corporation_id 
FROM 
  invoices i
WHERE 
  ((((YEAR(sent_at) = 2014) 
    AND (i.product_type_id IN (2,3,4))) 
  AND (i.removed = 0     AND i.activated = 1)
  ) 
  AND i.corporation_id IS NOT NULL) 
GROUP BY i.corporation_id
) ii ON(c.corporation_id = ii.corporation_id)
/* end of joins */
WHERE 
  ((((p.pass_type IN ('sport','culture','both')) 
    AND 
      (MONTH(p.valid_from) >= 1 
      AND MONTH(p.valid_from) <= 9 
      AND YEAR(p.valid_from) = YEAR(NOW()))) 
    AND (p.removed = 0 
      AND p.valid_from <= DATE('2014-09-29 11:55:26'))) 
  AND (c.removed = 0) 
  AND c.corporation_id IS NOT NULL) 
GROUP BY c.corporation_id;
```